# Not able to show the favicon to the uploads URL in WordPress

Tags: favicon

I am working on my client WordPress project and I have uploaded the PDF in the media. When I open the PDF URL, it is not showing the favicon.

My client wants to show the favicon in the PDF url.

I have added the favicon.ico in the directory where the wp-config is there but after that it is not showing the favicon.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just implemented this solution to my own website. I copied my site-icon.png file (the favicon that I inserted via the wordpress dashboard) to my root directory (public_html folder) and renamed it favicon.ico. To test that it was placed correctly I typed in the following www.mywebsite.co.za/favicon.ico and the favicon displayed. I then went and checked a pdf file and it worked.

Comment: I have added the favicon.ico to the public_html folder and it is showing in www.mywebsite.co.za/favicon.ico but not showing in the PDF URL

Comment: Just to be clear, you have put it in both this folder http://preview.measuremarketing.net and this folder http://preview.measuremarketing.net/larosebakery.com so in the public_html folder and public_html/larosebakery.com

Comment: Yes. Just check using the www.mywebsite.co.za/favicon.ico

Comment: Thank you, it has soled my problem.